# Using Google Apps Script and to update Slack status

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api

I'm just starting to learn the Slack API and I'm wanting to use Google Apps Script to set the [custom status](https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status#custom_status). Here's the code I've got (somehow there's something wrong with my profile variable:

```
function setStatus() {
 //https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status

  var token = MYTOKEN; //https://api.slack.com/apps
  var apiEndpoint = "https://slack.com/api/";
  var myUserID = MYUSERID;

  var method = "users.profile.set";
  var profile = {"status_text": "test"};
  var payload = {"token": token, "user" : myUserID, "profile" : profile};

  Logger.log(payload);

  var completeUrl = apiEndpoint + method;
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(completeUrl, {"method" : "post", "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)});
  var object = JSON.parse(jsonData.getContentText());
  Logger.log(object);
}
```

But the error message I'm getting is `{ok=false, error=invalid_form_data}`

I *have* successfully changed the presence via this code (just the "method" and "payload" variables have changed):

```
function setPresence() {
 //https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status

  var token = MYTOKEN; //https://api.slack.com/apps
  var apiEndpoint = "https://slack.com/api/";
  var myUserID = MYUSERID;

  var method = "users.setPresence";  
  var payload = {"token": token, "user" : myUserID, "presence" : "auto"}; //Presence can either be "auto" or "away"

  Logger.log(payload);

  var completeUrl = apiEndpoint + method;
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(completeUrl, {"method" : "post", "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)});
  var object = JSON.parse(jsonData.getContentText());
  Logger.log(object);
}
```

So if someone can help point out to me how I'm passing the `profile` in wrong, that'd be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is almost correct. I modified a little. Please check it. By this script, I have confirmed that "status_text" can be changed. And please include users.profile:write to the scope and retrieve access token again.

**Modified script :**

```
function setStatus() {
 //https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status

  var token = MYTOKEN; //https://api.slack.com/apps
  var apiEndpoint = "https://slack.com/api/";
  var myUserID = MYUSERID;

  var method = "users.profile.set";
  var profile = {"status_text": "test"};
  var payload = {token: token, user: myUserID, profile: JSON.stringify(profile)};

  Logger.log(payload);

  var completeUrl = apiEndpoint + method;
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(completeUrl, {method: "post", payload: payload});
  var object = JSON.parse(jsonData.getContentText());
  Logger.log(object);
}
```

Comment: Ah - that's what I was missing! A note for people that see this in the future: `var profile = {"status_text: "test"};` will let you set the message to `test`, but in order to set it back to blank, you must use `var profile = {"status_text": "", "status_emoji" : ""};` (you can't just use `var profile = {"status_text": ""};` - it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

I am also a .NET developer so for those people who want a C# solution, I have converted the final solution into .NET:

```
string apiEndpoint = "https://slack.com/api/";
string method = "users.profile.set";
string completeUrl = apiEndpoint + method;
string token = MYTOKEN; //Put your token here
string userID = MYUSERID; //Put your user id here
JObject profile = new JObject()
{
    {"status_text", "" },
    {"status_emoji", "" }
};
NameValueCollection payload = new NameValueCollection()
{
    {"token", token },
    {"user", userID },
    {"profile", profile.ToString() }
};

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var response = client.UploadValues(completeUrl, "POST", payload);
    string responseText = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetString(response);

    Console.WriteLine(responseText);
}
```

And if you don't want something that depends on [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) Then you can substitute this:

```
JObject profile = new JObject()
{
    {"status_text", "" },
    {"status_emoji", "" }
};
```

with

```
string profile = "{" +
                    "\"status_text\":\"\"," + /* e.g. "\"status_text\":\"test\","*/
                    "\"status_emoji\":\"\"" +
                 "}";
```